# rails on EC2, boot time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2

repeat test boot time of my rails app in EC2(micro instance), I get this:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-157-39-25:~/p/recite/current$ echo quit | time rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.1.1)
Switch to inspect mode.
quit
6.21user 0.65system 0:06.90elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 303552maxresident)k
0inputs+16outputs (0major+36215minor)pagefaults 0swaps
ubuntu@ip-10-157-39-25:~/p/recite/current$ echo quit | time rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.1.1)
Switch to inspect mode.
quit
18.03user 1.78system 0:19.84elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 303472maxresident)k
0inputs+8outputs (0major+36007minor)pagefaults 0swaps
ubuntu@ip-10-157-39-25:~/p/recite/current$ echo quit | time rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.1.1)
Switch to inspect mode.
quit
62.65user 6.28system 1:16.85elapsed 89%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 303760maxresident)k
0inputs+24outputs (0major+35592minor)pagefaults 0swaps
ubuntu@ip-10-157-39-25:~/p/recite/current$ echo quit | time rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.1.1)
Switch to inspect mode.
quit
6.21user 0.65system 0:06.90elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 303616maxresident)k
0inputs+24outputs (0major+35598minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Why the boot time changed between 6s to 62s ?

I am using ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 0):

Type `top` command and see which process eats your memory

Answer (score 0):

Try to find out if you are calling any external services during loading (initializers, application.rb ...)

Comment: No, just standard gems. and I find the time is excuted in ruby require  statement, why sometimes "require" so slow?